# DynamicLINQ - Escaping double quotes inside strings

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to do a dynamic filtering system using the ***DynamicLINQ*** library. I have everything working smoothly when you do something like: Find people with First Name is Bob:

```
Context.Users.Where("FirstName == \"Bob\"");
```

But I run into problems when I want to do: Find people with First Name is "Bob" (where Bob is stored in double quotes in the data source).

I tried a few different things, including escaping an escaped double quote and a few other variants:

```
Context.Users.Where("FirstName == \"\\\"Bob\\\"\"");
// or as a literal for readability
Context.Users.Where(@"FirstName == ""\""Bob\""""");
// From comments below
Context.Users.Where("FirstName == \"\"Bob\"\"");
```

None of these work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT** - I'm just dealing with the resulting string right now. The actual string is generated from a model.

Comment: can you use `string.Replace` or `RegEx`?

Comment: Maybe this? `"FirstName == \"\"Bob\"\""`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Not sure how that would help? They still produce a string in the end.

Comment: @RichardRout you can try parametrize your query like this `Context.Users.Where("FirstName == @0", "\"Bob\"");`

Comment: Grundy,  That's a good suggestion!!!

Comment: @Grundy that appears to work. I'd have to make some changes to get it to behave like this. Thanks for a valid solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want use in clause some specific string with special symbols then better way, as i think, use paramtrized form like this

```
Context.Users.Where("FirstName == @0", "\"Bob\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is you can not use `.Where()` to do dynamic linq evaluations as you have written. The reason is because `Where()` does not understand what `FirstName` is, and was never intended to do dynamic Linq expressions.  You would use where like the following
`.Where( x => x.FirstName == "\"Bob\"");` and that will work for sure.

A good head start is to use an existing Library found on ScottGu's Blog as follows:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

He has a download with code that will do everything you are describing.  It will take a little time to digest the library but I have used it in a project and it works great.  You need to know a little bit about Lambdas and you will go far.

Hope this helps :)  Good Question, I have been there and done that.  It was tricky finding this solution.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
EDIT

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Look at Dynamic.cs:

Line 2123 the following code exists in the method `ParseToken()`.

```
            case '"':
            case '\'':
                char quote = ch;
                do
                {
                    NextChar();
                    while (textPos < textLen && ch != quote) NextChar();
                    if (textPos == textLen)
                        throw ParseError(textPos, Res.UnterminatedStringLiteral);
                    NextChar();
                } while (ch == quote);
                t = TokenId.StringLiteral;
                break;
```

What this parser appears to be doing is: when it reads the second `"` in `[""Bob""]` it returns a null string Literal, thinking it has found the end of the string literal, then it would parse an identifier `[Bob]` and then another null string literal.  Somehow you will have to modify the parser to look for `""` as a token.

Maybe in `ParseComparison()` on line 766 you can devise a way to look for null String Literal followed by an identifier followed by another null String Literal. ???

Easy solution is to Replace `"` with null since rewriting the parser looks like some major effort.

Comment: Clearly he is not using LINQ already, else his code wouldn't even compile, let alone run.  He is using the Dynamic LINQ library, as he made very clear in his question.

Comment: Thanks @Servy - as stated I am using the DynamicLinq library. Will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, sorry I did not realize that.  I used it a bit differently and wrote a rules engine around it.  Another Thought.  In Dynamic.cs there is the enum TokenId.  In my version I do not see that they are parsing for the ".  That leads me to think that it does not account for that usage.  You could do as  DJ KRAZE said and remove all " from the string before evaluation.

Comment: Another thought is to set a break point in the code at NextToken(), ParsePrimaryStart(), ParseStringLiteral, etc where the TokenId.StringLiteral is used in code to see how it is parsing your expression.  From that you should be able to see how to modify the library.  Once you find the right spot then you can modify how it is building the lamda.