# Linq dynamic having issue with double quote

Tags: sql-server, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

I am `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` to generate dynamic linq query which featch records from db context.

I generate where clause in string format for dynamic linq, It works perfectly if input does not have any double quote. However, it throws error once input string contains double quote.

I followed Stack Overflow existing solution [dynamiclinq-escaping-double-quotes-inside-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200032/dynamiclinq-escaping-double-quotes-inside-strings) but it does not helped because I wanted to use LIKE operator.

I'm using **Contains** condition in my where clause because I need LIKE operator for query. Please follow below sample code...

```
//name should contains  "6"" WHITE COLOR

var whereClause = "(!flag.Contains(\"D\")) AND (Name.Contains(\"\"6\"\" WHITE COLOR\"\"))";

var result = context.Product.Where(whereClause).ToList();
```

Once I execute above query it throws error as `')' or operator expected`. But as per above where clause it looks all bracket are fine not sure is it any issue with dynamic query dll.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the escape symbol `\`.

```
//name should contains  "6"" WHITE COLOR

var whereClause = "(!flag.Contains(\"D\")) AND (Name.Contains(\"\\\"6\\\"\\\" WHITE COLOR\"))";

var result = context.Product.Where(whereClause).ToList();
```

Or use parameterization.

```
//name should contains  "6"" WHITE COLOR

var flag = "\"D\"";
var name = "\"6\"\" WHITE COLOR";
var whereClause = "(!flag.Contains(@0)) AND (Name.Contains(@1))";

var result = context.Product.Where(whereClause, @0, @1).ToList();
```

Comment: If I escape the escape symbol than whereClause it self is not valid string because after that it contains double quote. It gives compile time error.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried with new edited version. Only parameterization solution works for me. For first   solution I still see the error as `')' or ',' expected`

Comment: I still don't understand why the first version doesn't work for you. Are you sure you copied and pasted it exactly as is? Anyway, if you're happy with the answer don't forget to upvote and accept it as an answer please.

Comment: Yes sure...But I am looking for a solution which works with first version because I have multiple autocomplete which may contain single or multiple selection which creates multiple AND/OR operator so going with parameterization version we need to modify entire logic and which will be big change for me. Any help with first version really help me.

Comment: I cannot help you anymore with the first version. I am sure it compiles fine. I even QuickWatch the value of the variable `whereClause`: it's how you want it... `(!flag.Contains("D")) AND (Name.Contains("\"6\"\" WHITE COLOR"))`. I'm convinced this is a copy&paste problem. Please try copying it again.

Comment: I extended the second solution so it works for N number of parameters `var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "@0", "\"D\"" },
    { "@1", "\"6\"\" WHITE COLOR" }
};
object[] values = dic.Values.ToArray();` and finally passed values as params `var result = context.Product.Where(whereClause, values).ToList();`