# Linq to SQL fails when where clause contains double quote special character

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Team

I have a Linq to SQL query which will fetch list of items from database. This works fine for most of the special characters but when I use double quote it fails with different errors based on input

- Unterminated string literal
- expression required
- ')' or ',' expected

I have a combobox which will look up search text is present in 4 columns (which column to look is configurable )of database table, so we form dynamic query like below

For example, Search text is ABC
We have a foreach to get all the columns list which we should check and the below query is formed by concatenation

```
dynamicQuery = "(Column1.Contains(\"ABC\") OR Column2.Contains(\"ABC\") OR Column3.Contains(\"ABC\") OR Column4.Contains(\"ABC\")"
```

If I give double quote in the search text it is properly escaped by C#. doublequote is replaced by backslash+doublequote and still fails.

```
from rangeVariable in DatabaseTable
where(dynamicQuery)
```

Real scenario query is having more business logic, but to I keep things simple with the above example.

Note: I tried replacing "\ with empty character which works fine.
I know regex to ignore double quote / prevent entering double quote is other options.
But my requirement is to accept any user input but giving matching items. I want to support double quote special character also.
[Linq dynamic having issue with double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082268/linq-dynamic-having-issue-with-double-quote) - use parametrization looks promising but I am unable to use this suggestion as while forming dynamic query either it translates column1.contains to false.

Comment: All c# string constants must be escaped. How are you turning a string into sql?

Comment: Try following : @"(Column1.Contains(""ABC"") OR Column2.Contains(""ABC"") OR Column3.Contains(""ABC"") OR Column4.Contains(""ABC"")

Comment: LINQ to SQL does not support where clauses as strings - what technology / library are you using for that?